# How to create offline route in ArcGIS sdk version 100.2.1

Tags: android, arcgis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android-api

I get this error while accessing from local database:

```
E/RoutingActivity: com.esri.arcgisruntime.ArcGISRuntimeException: Cannot call this method in this context
```

How to create offline route in ArcGIS sdk version 100.2.1? All examples are given in SDK version 10.2.9.

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/java/find-route

Comment: Actually i am asking for how to create it with offline maps database stored in device?